# Print the cards that I used after I typed yes to play again

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want this game to start each hand with the cards left over from the previous hand.  Instead, it begins with a complete, newly-shuffled deck.  How can I fix it to just continue?
I updated the code based in your advice but it doesnt display my show card thanks a lot

```
import random, sys

suits = ('Clubs', 'Spades', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds')
pip = ('Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King')
pipValues = {'Ace':11, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '10':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10}



class Card:


    def __init__(self, suit, pip):
        self.suit = suit
        self.pip = pip
        self.value = pipValues.get(pip)

    def __str__(self):
        thisCard = ""
        thisCard += str(self.pip)
        thisCard += str(self.suit)
        return (thisCard)

    def __repr__(self):
        thisCard = ""
        thisCard += str(self.pip)
        thisCard += str(self.suit)
        return (thisCard)




class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []
        self.handTotal = 0

    def __str__(self):
        printHand = ""
        for i in self.hand:
            printHand += str(i) + " "
        return (printHand)

    def __repr__(self):
        printHand = ""
        for i in self.hand:
            printHand += str(i) + " "
        return (printHand)


class Deck:



    def __init__(self):
        self.cardList = []
        #for each suit take every card
        for i in range(len(suits)):
            for j in range(len(pip)):
                self.cardList.append(Card(suits[i], pip[j]))



    def shuffle(self):
        random. shuffle (self.cardList)

    def dealOne(self, player):
        (player.hand).append(self.cardList[0])

        player.handTotal += self.cardList[0].value

        del self.cardList[0]
        print self.cardList
        return self.cardList


    def __str__(self):
        printString = ""
        for i in range(len(self.cardList)):
            if i % 13 == 0:
                printString += "\n \t"
                printString += str(self.cardList[i]) + " "
            else:
                printString += str(self.cardList[i]) + " "
        printString += "\n"


        return printString


def showHands(player, opponent):
    print ('Dealer shows ' + str(opponent.hand[0]) + ' faceup')
    print ('You show ' + str(player.hand[0]) +str(player.hand[0] ))


def playerTurn(deck, player, other):
    #First, check scores to see if either player has a blackjack:

    if player.handTotal == 21 or other.handTotal == 21:
        if other.handTotal == 21:
            print ('You hold ' + str(player) + 'for a total of ' + str(player.handTotal))
            print ("Dealer has " + str(other) + "for a total of 21")
            print ("Dealer has a Blackjack! Dealer wins!")
            print ("Thanks for playing. Come back again soon! ")
            message()
        else:
            print ("You hold " + str(player) + "for a total of 21")
            print ("You have a Blackjack! You win!")

            print ("Thanks for playing. Come back again soon! ")
            message()   

    hitOrStand = 0
    aces = False

    #IF TWO ACES
    if player.hand[0].pip == "A" and player.hand[1].pip == "A":
        player.hand[0].pipValue = 1

    if player.handTotal == 21:
            print ('You hold ' + str(player) + 'for a total of ' + str(player.handTotal))
            print ("Blackjack! You win!")
            print ("Thanks for playing. Come back soon!")
            print()
            message()
    while hitOrStand != 2:
        #check for aces
        for i in player.hand:
            if i.pip == "A" and i.value == 11:
                aces = True

        print ('You hold ' + str(player) + 'for a total of ' + str(player.handTotal))
        print()
        hitOrStand = input('Do you hit or stand? Enter "1" for hit and "2" for stand: ')
        while hitOrStand != 1 and hitOrStand != 2:
            try:
                hitOrStand = int(hitOrStand)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print ("Enter a valid integer \n")
            hitOrStand = input('Do you hit hit or stand? Enter "1" for hit and "2" for stand: ')
        print()

        if hitOrStand == 1:
            print('Card dealt:  ' + str(deck.cardList[0]))
            print()
            deck.dealOne(player)
            #check if an ace was drawn
            for i in player.hand:
                if i.pip == "A" and i.value == 11:
                    aces = True

        if player.handTotal == 21:
            print ('You hold ' + str(player) + 'for a total of ' + str(player.handTotal))
            print ("Blackjack!! You Win!")
            print()
            print ("Thanks for playing. Come back soon!")
            message()

        if player.handTotal > 21:
            #check for aces
            if aces:
                print ('You hold ' + str(player) + 'for a total of ' + str(player.handTotal))
                print ("Over 21. Value of ace changed to 1")
                #chanlge value of ace and hand
                player.handTotal = player.handTotal - 10
                for i in player.hand:
                    if i.pip == "A" and i.value == 11:
                        i.value = 1
                #check for other standard aces
                aces = False
                for i in player.hand:
                    if i.pip == "A" and i.value == 11:
                        aces = True
            else:
                print ('You hold ' + str(player) + 'for a total of ' + str(player.handTotal))
                print ("You Bust! Dealer Wins!")
                #exit, since you're a loser
                print ("Thanks for Playing! Come Back Soon!")
                print()
                raise SystemExit

        if hitOrStand == 2:
            print ('You stand at: ' + str(player.handTotal))
            print()

    print ("Now Dealer's Turn")
    print ()
def message():
        again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? (Y/N) : ")
        if(again == "Y" or again == "y"):
            main()
        else:
            print "\n\n-------Thank you for playing!--------\n\n"
            exit()

def opponentTurn(deck, player, other):
    if other.handTotal == 21:
        raise SystemExit
    aces = False
    hitOrStand = 0

    #IF TWO ACES
    if player.hand[0].pip == "A" and player.hand[1].pip == "A":
        player.hand[0].pipValue = 1

    while hitOrStand != 2:
        #check for aces
        for i in player.hand:
            if i.pip == "A" and i.value == 11:
                aces = True


        print ('Dealer holds ' + str(player) + 'for a total of ' + str(player.handTotal))
        print()
        #if blackjack
        if player.handTotal == 21:
            print ("Dealer has a BlackJack! Dealer Wins!")
            break
        if player.handTotal <21 and other.handTotal == 21:
            print ("Dealer's hand is " + str(player.handTotal) + ". You have a Blackjack! Congratulations! You win! ")
            break

        if player.handTotal < other.handTotal:
            hitOrStand = 1
        if player.handTotal >= other.handTotal:
            hitOrStand = 2

        if hitOrStand == 1:
            print("Dealer hits. " + 'Card dealt:  ' + str(deck.cardList[0]))
            deck.dealOne(player)
            #check if an ace was drawn
            for i in player.hand:
                if i.pip == "A" and i.value == 11:
                    aces = True

        if player.handTotal > 21:
            #check for aces
            if aces:
                print ('Dealer holds ' + str(player) + 'for a total of ' + str(player.handTotal))
                print ("Over 21. Value of ace changed to 1")
                #chanlge value of ace and hand
                player.handTotal = player.handTotal - 10
                for i in player.hand:
                    if i.pip == "A" and i.value == 11:
                        i.value = 1

                #check for other standard aces
                aces = False
                for i in player.hand:
                    if i.pip == "A" and i.value == 11:
                        aces = True
            else:
                print ('Dealer holds ' + str(player) + 'for a total of ' + str(player.handTotal))
                print ("Dealer Busts! You Win!")
                message()


        if hitOrStand == 2:
            print ("Dealer stands at " + str(player.handTotal))
            print ("Your score is " + str(other.handTotal))
            print ("Dealer Wins!")
            message()
#who won
def main():
    cardDeck = Deck()
    print ('Initial Deck: ')
    print(cardDeck)

    cardDeck.shuffle()
    print ('Shuffled Deck: ')
    print(cardDeck)

    keep_playing = True
    while keep_playing:

        player = Player()
        opponent = Player()

        #give each player 2 cards, alternating
        cardDeck.dealOne(player)
        cardDeck.dealOne(opponent)
        cardDeck.dealOne(player)
        cardDeck.dealOne(opponent)

        print ('Deck after giving 2 cards each')
        print (cardDeck)

        #show 1 faceup card for each player
        showHands(player,opponent)

        #start playing
        playerTurn(cardDeck,player, opponent)
        opponentTurn(cardDeck, opponent, player)

        again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? (Y/N) : ")
        keep_playing = again in "Yy"

    # Reach here after dropping out of the while loop
    print "\n\n-------Thank you for playing!--------\n\n"
main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  We shouldn't have to wade through over 300 lines of code to track an end-of-loop problem.  Most of all, we shouldn't have to enter variable input to find the problem.

Comment: i edited it I am sorry and thank you for guiding

Comment: This code doesn't execute.  It has indentation errors and it's missing required pieces.  It looks like all you did was to delete the top of the program, rather than editing the code's functionality to show the problem.

Comment: Also, even with the full code, I'm not clear what you expect.  The program displays the hand as I play it.  I don't see any attempt to print my cards from hand 1 when I start hand 2, which is what you seem to want.  I also don't see any attempt to print my cards at the end of hand 1.

Comment: I edited it.. it has error in message function

Comment: really thank you for help

Comment: You recursively call main from main. This is *bad*. The correct way is to build a loop that consistently calls the appropriate functions (at least `playerTurn` and `opponentTurn`), and break out from the loop (or exit program) when the user wants to stop.

Comment: Thank you for help I am new in python can I is it posibble to create a new function that will save cards that has given to me and remove it in deck if I restart the game? cause if I remove the other functions in message and left only the main function the game just restart and gives 52 cards is there wasy way to implement it ? thank you very much really much appreciated

Comment: That clarifies the question better; you want to start the next next with the *deck* left over from the previous game.

Comment: yes thats what I am trying to do but I always got error I am looking for the best advice to implement it in a better way cause it seems like what I am doing is wrong putting some functions in the message function thank you very much for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have one game continue from where the previous one left off.  The current problem is that you call **main** recursively.  This starts over from the beginning, shuffling a full deck, etc.

Instead, you would want a main program something like this:

```
def main():
    cardDeck = Deck()
    print ('Initial Deck: ')
    print(cardDeck)

    cardDeck.shuffle()
    print ('Shuffled Deck: ')
    print(cardDeck)

    keep_playing = True
    while keep_playing:

        player = Player()
        opponent = Player()

        #give each player 2 cards, alternating
        cardDeck.dealOne(player)
        cardDeck.dealOne(opponent)
        cardDeck.dealOne(player)
        cardDeck.dealOne(opponent)

        print ('Deck after giving 2 cards each')
        print (cardDeck)

        #show 1 faceup card for each player
        showHands(player,opponent)

        #start playing
        playerTurn(cardDeck,player, opponent)
        opponentTurn(cardDeck, opponent, player)

        again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? (Y/N) : ")
        keep_playing = again in "Yy"

    # Reach here after dropping out of the while loop
    print "\n\n-------Thank you for playing!--------\n\n"
```

This gets rid of your **message** function and the recursive call to **main**.

Comment: I already updated it thank you very much but it doesnt show my show card thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Which cards do you want to see?  The remaining deck?  If that's the case, then put the final **print(cardDeck)** inside the loop.

Comment: The output of the code is if I execute it the first thing is ask me do you want to play again then if I click Y it shows me the initial deck and shuffle deck It didnt display the show card function wherein it will show what card the dealer and the player has Thank you alot

Comment: That's because you changed what I gave you to work that way.  Your current posting has removed several routines, including playerTurn and opponentTurn.  However, I commented those out and replaced your main program with the one I gave you above.  The program prints each hand and *then* asks if you want to play again.

Comment: I changed it already it displaying everything now thank you for well explained but if I click yes it shows me that my initial deck is 52 still and the cards that used in the previous game is still in the intial deck when I typed yes thank you a lot really

Comment: Great.  When I run the code, it doesn't reset; the deck keeps getting smaller as I go, until I run out of cards.  Did you leave the deck creation *before* the loop, *before* the **while** line?  That's the critical part.

Comment: I updated the code above maybe I did mistake in the code thats why the cards I used in previous game still in deck after  I type Y...Please kindly take a look I am sorry and really thank you you are very nice

Comment: I run it its working now I realize my mistake thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

See the [repl.it](https://repl.it/GjNL/9) for a complete solution:

There are a lot of issues, here are a few of overarching themes:

## If you're having to repeat yourself, you're doing it wrong:

```
aces = False
#IF TWO ACES
if player.hand[0].pip == "A" and player.hand[1].pip == "A":
    player.hand[0].pipValue = 1
```

```
#check for aces
    for i in player.hand:
        if i.pip == "A" and i.value == 11:
            aces = True
```

```
#check if an ace was drawn
        for i in player.hand:
            if i.pip == "A" and i.value == 11:
                aces = True
```

```
#check for aces
if aces:
    print ('You hold ' + str(player) + 'for a total of ' + str(player.handTotal))
    print ("Over 21. Value of ace changed to 1")
    #chanlge value of ace and hand
    player.handTotal = player.handTotal - 10
    for i in player.hand:
        if i.pip == "A" and i.value == 11:
            i.value = 1
    #check for other standard aces
    aces = False
    for i in player.hand:
        if i.pip == "A" and i.value == 11:
            aces = True
```

Each of those is used twice... I replaced it by letting my players hand decide it's own value:

```
@property  
def handTotal(self):
  while sum(card.value for card in self.hand) > 21 and \
        any(card.pip == 'Ace' and card.value == 11 for card in self.hand):
    for card in self.hand:
      if card.pip == 'Ace' and card.value == 11:
        card.value = 1
        break
  return sum(card.value for card in self.hand)
```

The `@property` decorator forces it to recalculate every time someone asks for the handTotal.

---

## Telling main you want to keep playing

You need to `return` a value all the way back to main, in some way. Because you already have some global state variables, I added `playing = True`, then:

```
def message():
    global playing
    again = input("Do you want to play again? (Y/N) : ")
    if again.lower() == "n":
        print("\n\n-------Thank you for playing!--------\n\n")
        playing = False
    return True # Tells `turn()` the game is over
```

Comment: thank you for help I'll try your suggestion thank you

Comment: @Aika see the repl.it link at the top for a complete fix... I may hop on later and explain the rest... we'll see.

Comment: I run it its working but I wanted to print my cards in the deck after I typed Yes to see if it removed my previous card that given to player and the dealer that I had in the previous game thank you alot I really appreciate it thank you

Comment: @Aika my example takes it one step further... it pulls from the deck until it has no more cards, then shuffles a new deck. It could be further improved by shuffling a new deck which does not contain cards already on the table.